# ruby on rails 3 tutorial - failing integration test chapter 9 - ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/signout"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rails-routing

I'm at the end of chapter 9 of Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial (early Kindle edition of the book, not the online version) and ran into a failing integration test (users_spec.rb). I've been searching for a while, but non of the suggestions I found so far worked out for me. I downloaded the source code of the tutorial of both the first and second edition and they run fine, so it really looks like there's something wrong in the configuration of my application but as a rails newbie, it feels like looking for the needle in a haystack so any help is welcome.

the error message: ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/signout"

the users_spec.rb contains this

```
    ...
       describe "success" do
          it "should sign a user in and out" do
             user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
             visit signin_path
             fill_in :email, :with => user.email
             fill_in :password, :with => user.password
             click_button
             controller.should be_signed_in
             click_link "Sign out"
             controller.should_not be_signed_in
          end
       end
    ...
```

my application.html.erb looks like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title><%= @title %></title>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'default' %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      <%= render 'layouts/stylesheets' %>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class='container'>
        <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
        <section class = "round">
          <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
            <div class="flash <%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
          <% end %>
          <%= yield %>
        </section>
        <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
        <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

my application_controller.rb looks like this

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      protect_from_forgery
      include SessionsHelper
    end
```

my application.js looks like this

```
    // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
    // listed below.
    //
    // Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
    // or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
    //
    // It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
    // the compiled file.
    //
    // WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
    // GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
    //
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require_tree .
```

the _header.html.erb file contains this

```
    ...
      <% if signed_in? %>
      <li><%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, :method => :delete %></li>
      <% else %>
    ...
```

my routes.rb contains this

```
    ...
      get "sessions/new"

      resources :users
      resources :sessions, :only =>[:new, :create, :destroy]

      match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
      match '/about', :to => 'pages#about'
      match '/help', :to => 'pages#help'
      match '/signup', to: 'users#new'

      match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'
      match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

      root :to => 'pages#home'
    ...
```

my sessions_controller.rb contains this

```
    ...
      def destroy
        sign_out
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    ...
```

the sessions_helper.rb contains this

```
    ...
      def sign_out
        cookies.delete(:remember_token)
        @current_user = nil
      end
    ...
```

this is what I get when I execute rake routes

```
    sessions_new GET    /sessions/new(.:format)   sessions#new
           users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
                 POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
        new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
       edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
            user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
                 PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
                 DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
        sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)       sessions#create
     new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)   sessions#new
         session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)   sessions#destroy
         contact        /contact(.:format)        pages#contact
           about        /about(.:format)          pages#about
            help        /help(.:format)           pages#help
          signup        /signup(.:format)         users#new
          signin        /signin(.:format)         sessions#new
         signout DELETE /signout(.:format)        sessions#destroy
```

my gemfile looks like this

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

    gem 'pg'
    gem 'gravatar_image_tag'
    gem 'jquery-rails'

    group :development do
      gem 'rspec-rails'
      gem 'annotate'
    end

    group :test do
      gem 'rspec'
      gem 'webrat'
      gem 'spork'
      gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    end
```

when running bundler install I get this as output:

```
    Using rake (0.9.2.2)
    Using i18n (0.6.1)
    Using multi_json (1.3.6)
    Using activesupport (3.2.8)
    Using builder (3.0.4)
    Using activemodel (3.2.8)
    Using erubis (2.7.0)
    Using journey (1.0.4)
    Using rack (1.4.1)
    Using rack-cache (1.2)
    Using rack-test (0.6.2)
    Using hike (1.2.1)
    Using tilt (1.3.3)
    Using sprockets (2.1.3)
    Using actionpack (3.2.8)
    Using mime-types (1.19)
    Using polyglot (0.3.3)
    Using treetop (1.4.11)
    Using mail (2.4.4)
    Using actionmailer (3.2.8)
    Using arel (3.0.2)
    Using tzinfo (0.3.33)
    Using activerecord (3.2.8)
    Using activeresource (3.2.8)
    Using annotate (2.5.0)
    Using diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    Using factory_girl (4.1.0)
    Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
    Using json (1.7.5)
    Using rdoc (3.12)
    Using thor (0.16.0)
    Using railties (3.2.8)
    Using factory_girl_rails (4.1.0)
    Using gravatar_image_tag (1.1.3)
    Using jquery-rails (2.1.3)
    Using nokogiri (1.5.5)
    Using pg (0.14.1)
    Using bundler (1.2.0)
    Using rails (3.2.8)
    Using rspec-core (2.11.1)
    Using rspec-expectations (2.11.3)
    Using rspec-mocks (2.11.3)
    Using rspec (2.11.0)
    Using rspec-rails (2.11.4)
    Using spork (0.9.2)
    Using webrat (0.7.3)
```

maybe interesting to mention is that when running my application through rails s, it's failing as well, so it's not only a webrat or failing integration issue. when looking at the html source in firbug, it shows that the javascript I would expect to show up is not there

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1">
```

[image: signed in state]

when clicking "Sign out" this is the result
[image: failing sign out]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong as far as what you showed. Do the usual, clearing browser cache, bundle install, restarting server and see if that works.

Comment: in your `user_spec` file, how capybara know which button you want to click with this code: `click_button` ? specify a id, text, or value of button and try again

Comment: wow, I just realized you are not even using capybara

Comment: indeed, I'm using webrat. I quickly tried switching to capybara, but that resulted in 23 failing tests (including the one this post is about) due to the syntax differences I guess. So before adapting all these tests to the capybara syntax, I want to make sure this test is successful.

Comment: In case you haven't realized, you should not be using rails 3.2 for following the 3.0 tutorial, to avoid unnecessary frustration.

Answer (score 0):

**Executive Summary**

You are using [webrat](https://github.com/brynary/webrat) instead of [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara), which would explain why the issue I describe below came up. Change:

```
gem 'webrat'
```

to

```
gem 'capybara'
```

in your Gemfile, and the javascript click handler for DELETE requests should work fine.

For a more in-depth discussion of the issues involved, see my original answer below.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

This is a tricky one. Looks to me like the problem is that javascript is not turned on for your test.

Some background: Rails uses a scripting adapter called [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) to do various things such as force confirmation dialogs (the "Are you sure?" message you get when you try to delete a record) and make non-GET requests from hyperlinks (so you can click a "Delete" link and your browser will send a DELETE request).

In your routes.rb, you have:

```
signout DELETE /signout(.:format)        sessions#destroy
```

What this says is: when a DELETE request comes to the URL `/signout`, sign the user out. By default, however, when you click a link on a page to the URL `/signout`, your browser will send a GET request, not a DELETE request.

When you include the option `method: destroy` in your call to `link_to` here:

```
link_to "Sign out", signout_path, :method => :delete
```

What this does is tell Rails to add an attribute `data-method="delete"` to the attributes on the link in the view (check the actual HTML rendered to see that this is true). This attribute is like a flag: it tells jquery-ujs to add a click handler which turns any click on this element from a GET into a DELETE. For more details, see [this article](http://railsdog.com/blog/2011/02/28/callbacks-in-jquery-ujs-in-rails3/). Note also that Hartl mentions this point in [a footnote](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#fn-8_8).

But what happens if javascript is not enabled in this case? Well, that last click handler is not added, and your browser treats the link to `/signout` like any other link on the page, so when you click it you send a GET request to that URL. However Rails does not have any path for a GET request to `/signout`, hence it spits out the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] “/signout”
```

That's the cause of the problem here.

Now for the solution, I believe you should be able to add an option to your test `js: true` which will enable javascript, like so:

```
it "should sign a user in and out", js: true do
  ...
end
```

If you're using Selenium, the default javascript driver, this will actually open a browser window -- to run the js test without the window add the [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) gem to your Gemfile and set the driver using `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit`. See the section of [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara?view=asciicast) on testing javascript for details on using javascript in Rspec requests specs.

Comment: I just verified this on my reference copy and read about https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/64, which means that `method: :delete` should work fine even with `rack_test`. What is interesting is that I had `friendly_forwardings_spec` failing instead of `users_spec` (both are request specs involving sign out).  As an aside, the `via: :delete` constraint is not present in older versions of the tutorial.

Comment: You mean you verified that this should work without `js: true`? I'm not quite sure why js is not working on the link, but from the error it's pretty clear that what I wrote in the first half of the answer is correct. I also found it strange though that Hartl's tutorial didn't mention anything about this, so I'm guessing it's a configuration issue specific to the OP's environment.

Comment: yes, this could be a bug with capybara or some other dependency, but I believe the test is supposed to work with rack_test

Comment: Possibly related: I see webrat but not capybara in the bundler output.

Comment: Oh that's probably the problem, the OP is not using capybara! See the Gemfile. That would explain it.

Comment: thanks for the context information, it really helps in better understanding how things work under the hood. In the mean time I'm trying to swap webrat out and capybara in.

Comment: when I run my application through rails s, when clicking "Sign out", I get the same error as with my failing integration test: No route matches [GET] "/signout". when looking at the html source in firebug, no javascript script is showing other than the <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/default.js">. so it seems that the required <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"> I see appearing when running the code of the tutorial, is missing here. any clue on how to resolve this?

Comment: Normally in a rails app, you have a file `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`, and in that file you have `require` directives to include various javascript dependencies. To get jquery and jquery_ujs, you need to make sure that you have the lines `//= require jquery` and `//=require jquery_ujs`, in that order. If you're using `default.js` instead of `application.js` then add those two lines to the top of that file.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that you are using webrat:

```
    group :test do
      gem 'rspec'
      gem 'webrat'
      gem 'spork'
      gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    end
```

The last version of that tutorial that still uses webrat is 3.0, and the version of the test you are referencing is from [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out?version=3.0), which means you are trying to follow the older 3.0 tutorial without using the [Gemfile](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages?version=3.0#code%3agemfile_rspec) that has been tested to work with it.

While there *may* be an [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ruby-capybara/zKE-Vqr-uVA/7w-viqEUAm4J) with capybara with regard to handling `data-method: :delete` since the behavior would be changed in the next major version, this is not the problem you are facing.